# Is there a way to use Microsoft Word Save as -> html from command line or python?

Tags: ms-word, command-line-interface, ms-office

I am trying to automate an existing process that uses html files produced from docx for post-treatment.

I know Word is producing a lot of garbage while converting to html, and I have already tested Mammoth https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js/, but the process using the html file as input is designed to support the html format from Word and I cannot touch that process.

My question is: is there a way to call the Save As -> html in Word from command line or eventually in Python? Something similar to what exists in OpenOffice with:

```
soffice --convert-to html:HTML
```

I know also about win32com, but this package exists only in Pythong for Windows, not for Mac, or eventually on other platforms as Linux.